# How to join multiple lists in SharePoint 2013 on-premises?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql

sorry if my question is for old versions. the system I have access is sharepoint 2013, InfoPath , sharepoint designer. I need a list for report that I have to joint multiple list for retrieving the fields I need, When I would like to join multiple list or library in sharepoint 2013 (and some times using sub-query like what we do in Sql-Server) what is the best practice.

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join functionality available on a backend: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539975(v=office.14)

If you don't have backend and use InfoPath from designer you can try only rules, triggering and sub query. From UI, designer etc. Joins feature not available.

Comment: Thanks, can you send me address of samples about use InfoPath from designer you can try only rules, triggering and sub query.

Comment: Not more info in web about InfoPath right now i have 10 years ago book about it but you can try found like that as starting point: https://wonderlaura.com/2011/08/01/infopath-query-specific-sharepoint-list-data/